# Rename table without losing any data and connections with other tables, views etc

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I would like to change the name of a few tables. The problem is that the name of a table is connected with keys from other tables. The name of a table is also used in views etc. So if i would change the table name, i would lose all of that connections, or i would have to manualy change the name of all connections, which is time consuming.

Is there a way to change a table name without losing any data?
I am using Sql Server Management Studio.

Comment: If you aren't using a SQL Server Data Tools database project in which you can refactor your entire solution following this change, you are going to need to change everything manually.  Tools such as [Apex SQL Search](https://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_search.aspx) can help you find any objects that reference the table name.

Comment: I will change it manualy, with a help of a Apex SQL Search.